# Matlab data explorer app with ASPEN Sqlplus

Tags: sql, matlab, sqlplus, aspen

Is there a way to use the data explorer app with Aspen sql plus on matlab2013b to join tables and import data?

I can use it with a normal sql databasis, but when I try to use it with sqlplus it does not want to work.

I can script code to import the data from sqlplus, but it would be very useful to join and link the tables "visually" like with normal a sql database.

Comment: Note that MATLAB R2013b is a 7 year old version. It lacks a lot of the functionality of later versions, especially since the big overhaul after R2016b. It might be difficult for you to find support for this explicit version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Adriaan. I assumed as much. Unfortunately that is the license and version that the company I work at use. I am just hoping that someone can help as it will help immensely with improting my data.

Comment: SQL plus is an odbc driver. So if you have an odbc connector it could work. Search 'connection string' in sqlplus writer help. Also you can have a look on ip21 web api.